# Updating branch in Fossil

Tags: branch, commit, fossil

I am working on a project, using Fossil for version controlling and organizing it. I have some branches other than my main trunk branch, and want to update (commit) only a single branch. Doing commit will push my changes on a branch to the main Files (i am hosting my project on Chiselapp) 
. How is it possible to update or commit only a single branch without affecting the main files?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "main Files"? The files in the `trunk` branch, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A commit only ever affects a single branch**. Except perhaps after merging two branches, but I'm assuming you haven't been doing that.

The only thing I can think of is that the skin you're using has a "Files" menu item that links to `dir?ci=tip`. The `tip` is a special name for the most recent commit. Which means that, if you make a commit in a different branch than `trunk`, that "Files" menu item will now show you the files of that other branch.

The hackish temporary way to fix that is to make a commit in `trunk` afterwards, so that `tip` refers to `trunk` again. But that's not ideal.

The easiest way to permanently fix this, is by choosing a different skin which doesn't do that, or by editing your skin's header, and replacing the link to `dir?ci=tip` by another link, `dir?ci=trunk` for example. That way, that menu item will always show the files in the `trunk` branch.

Answer (score 0):

Fossil unlike Git pushes/pulls **all** branches and tags at once*. The reason (apart from being by design) is that Fossil repository is a database, push/full synchronizes the database in the respective direction.

This means if you committed changes on several branches then all of them will be pushed to the remote.

*UNLESS, the changes are done on **private** branches (see `fossil help` for `fossil commit --branch --private`, `fossil branch new --private`).

Private commits/branches by default are excluded from push/pull. To also include these use `--private` option (see `fossil help` for `fossil push --private`).

Once the changes have been pushed, they are integrated in the remote repo and can be viewed in the remote repo's web-GUI as individual commits or via the branch to which they belong. The view includes the `Files` section that reflects the repo contents (snapshot) at the commit's version.

To answer your question: if you committed changes to existing `trunk` branch, they will be pushed to the remote `trunk` as well. If you don't want to make changes to the remote `trunk`, then make your changes in your new branch (to be pushed as a new branch) or in your private branch (will NOT be pushed by default).